# Tunneling Redhawk Component CORBA interface thru firewall

Tags: redhawksdr

I have a peculiar problem I'm trying to solve that involves using an interface implemented by redhawk components across a firewall.
I found the following how-to on the omniORB site for tunneling CORBA interfaces through a firewall (scroll down to SSH tunnels w/omniORB):

http://www.omniorb.net/omniwiki/UsefulTips

In a nutshell, the how-to says to start your server on one side of tunnel (registers interface object with name service), then use the omniORB tools 'nameclt' and 'convertior' to modify the IOR to point to other side of tunnel and rebind IOR to interface object.

Using the omniORB Echo example, I can successfully use technique above to tunnel GIOP messages and have a client on one machine access the Echo interface on another across the tunnel. (Assume for the moment that the Name Service can be seen by both machines on either end of tunnel).

The problem I have is replicating this technique using Redhawk components.  If I have a component implementing the "echo" interface, I'm unclear as to how I can retrieve the IOR and modify using the technique above so that a component on the other side of the tunnel can see it.  I don't see the interface registered with the Name Service, only the domain and device manager hosting the component.  I could be wrong but I believe this is because the SCA CF wraps these interfaces inside of Domain Manager/Device Manager.

I think I can use the Redhawk Python environment to get what I'm after but I'm unsure how to proceed.  I believe I can get the domain, device, interface and IOR as follows:

```
from ossie.utils import redhawk
from omniORB import CORBA
orb = CORBA.ORB_init(0, CORBA.ORB_ID)

dom1 = redhawk.attach("Domain1")
device1 = dom1.devices[0]
echoIF = device1.getPort("EchoIn")

echoIOR = orb.object_to_string(echoIF)
```

This seems to give me the IOR for the Echo interface (using catior tool shows correct interface), but then I'm unsure how to proceed.  I tried copying the IOR and using 'convertior' inside a terminal to modify the IOR and then using the naming service inside Python to rebind:

```
namesvc = orb.resolve_initial_references("NameService")
namecontext = namesvc._narrow(CosNaming.NamingContext)
namecontext.rebind(echoIOR, echoIF)
```

But this throws an exception "Expecting sequence, got type 'str' ".
Looking at rebind interface, I probably need an object key to go with the IOR but I don't know how to get that.  I was hoping the Python environment would just let me use the object reference as an argument to rebind the IOR, especially since the orb provides a mechanism to go directly between object reference and IOR string.

Another problem, assuming the client component is running in another domain on other side of the tunnel, once I succeed in rebinding the server IOR, how does the client component get it to resolve the connection?  If the interface isn't listed by name in the Name Service, then how will the client domain see it?

I feel like I'm very close to getting this working I'm just missing a step or two.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The rebind operation requires a CosNaming name and a reference. The name follows the form "naming_context/object_name", but it needs to be put into a sequence of class `CosNaming.NameComponent`. `omniORB` includes a helper for that:

```
from omniORB import URI
name = URI.stringToName("naming_context_1/naming_context_n/object_name")
```

so in your case:

```
echoName=URI.stringToName('name_in_nameservice')
namecontext.rebind(echoName, echoIF)
```

If you use `nameclt` to look at the name service, you'll see your binding there.

Setting up your system to be able to work through firewalls is very configuration specific, so my ability to provide insight is very limited